# Face.com API upload image from python

Tags: python, api, http, post, mime

I'm trying to upload an image to the Face.com API. It either takes a url to an image, or images can be uploaded directly. [Their website](http://developers.face.com/docs/api/faces-detect/) says:

> A requests that uploads a photo must be formed as a MIME multi-part
>   message sent using POST data. Each argument, including the raw image
>   data, should be specified as a separate chunk of form data.

Problem is, I don't know exactly what that means. Right now my code looks like this:

```
import urllib
import json

apikey = "[redacted]"
secret = "[redacted]"

img = raw_input("Enter the URL of an image: ");

url = "http://api.face.com/faces/detect.json?api_key=" + apikey + "&api_secret=" + secret + "&urls=" + urllib.quote(img) + "&attributes=all"
data = json.loads(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
```

How can I convert this to work with a locally stored image?

Comment: Use requests: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to upload photo in Python to face.com API is just using the Python Client Library that can be downloaded form http://developers.face.com/download/.

You got 2 there. Both support uploading by passing filename to the detected method (as a different param than the urls).